# xml string to Object mapping does not happen

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have a stored procedure that sends a response as an xml string

So I've create a class and want to map the response of this store procedure to an Object of some type

This is my class and it's proprieties.

The Populate method is where i want to do my xml to object mapping.

```
[XmlRoot("SiteItem")]
    public class SiteItem : BaseEntity<SiteItem>
    {
        [XmlElement("IdSiteItem")]
        public int IdSiteItem { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ItemName")]
        public string ItemName{ get; set; }

        public override SiteItem Populate(DataRow entity)
        {
            var column = entity["Column1"].ToString();
            XmlSerializer serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SiteItem));
        string result = column.Replace("<Root>", "");
            result = result.Replace("</Root>", "");
            result = result.Replace("</SiteItem>", "");
            result = result.Replace("/>", ">");
            result = result.Replace(">", "/>|");

        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> siteItems = result.Split('|').ToList();
        siteItems.RemoveAll(item => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item));

        foreach (var item in siteItems)
        {
            using (StringReader stream = new System.IO.StringReader(item))
            {
                SiteItem response = (SiteItem)serialize.Deserialize(stream); 

//=> response  always null
//=> stream has the following format 
//=> <SiteItem IdSiteItem=\"8436\" ItemName=\"demoweb\" >
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that the mapping from xml node to SiteItem does not happen, the props are their default values.

This is the type of response I have from the stored procedure

```
"<Root>
    <SiteItem IdSiteItem=\"8436\" ItemName=\"demoweb\" >
    <SiteItem IdSiteItem=\"8465\" ItemName=\"\" />
    <SiteItem IdSiteItem=\"8535\" ItemName=\"DocumentPreview\" /></SiteItem>
    <SiteItem IdSiteItem=\"7413\" ItemName=\"GlobalNews Search\"  />
    <SiteItem IdSiteItem=\"5838\" ItemName=\"GlobalQuestionsForm\" />
</Root>"
```

So what I did is first remove `<Root>` and `</root>`. Remove the `</SiteItem>` since not all elements have this node ending.

After I obtain a string that is free of Root and /SiteItem I've applied a delimiter "|" so that i can split and store the string as a list of strings 
each list item is a SiteItem node.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class SiteItem 
{
    [XmlElement("SiteItem")]
    public List<SiteItemChild> Child { get; set; }
}
```

And the class that represents the child

```
public class SiteItemChild  
{
      [XmlAttribute("IdSiteItem")]
      public int IdSiteItem { get; set; }

      [XmlAttribute("ItemName")]
      public int ItemName{ get; set; } 
}
```

this is the deserializer.

```
public SiteItem Deserialize(string xmlString)
{
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString));
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SiteItem));
        SiteItem @object = (SiteItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

       return @object;
    }
}
```

A better way for this situation.

```
public SiteItem Deserialize(string xmlString)
{
        string processedXml = xmlString.Replace("<Root>" , "");
        processedXml = processedXml.Replace("</Root>" , "");

        processedXml = processedXml.Replace("</SiteItem>", "");
        processedXml = processedXml.Replace(" />", ">");

        processedXml = processedXml.Replace(">", "></SiteItem>");
        processedXml = processedXml.Insert(0, "<Root>");
        processedXml = processedXml.Insert(processedXml.Length, "
         </Root>");

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(processedXml));
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SiteItem));
            SiteItem @object = (SiteItem)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            return @object;
        }
    }
```

Why I did this? Because some elements SiteItem nodes have "/>" ending others ">" and others " ... so i standardized by all SiteItems to have an ending tag.

The standard

In the last string processing part i just added the Root start and ending tag again.

Why i've choosen this solution? Specific to my case the business logic is done in procedures and the problem here is that some procedures send an xmlString other send dataSets.